# When doing a match with the traverse function with all equals

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1

In Orient DB, I understand a query like this:

```
match 
  {class: someNode, as: someNode, where: (id='123')}
  .out() {class: someNode as: relatedNode, while:(true), where:(relevance = true)}
return
  someNode
```

Will return someNode with ID 123 if any outnodes has relevance = true.  However, what if i want ALL outgoing nodes to be relevance = true connected to someNode?  Can I still do a match starting at someNode 123 going out where all = true?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
match 
  {class: someNode, as: someNode, 
   where: (id='123' AND out()[relevance != true).size() = 0}
return someNode
```

[edit]

If you need also connected nodes with the same features, you can do the following:

```
match 
  {class: someNode, as: someNode, 
   where: (id='123' AND out()[relevance != true).size() = 0}
  .out(){class: someNode, as: anotherNode, 
      while: (relevance = true AND out()[relevance != true).size() = 0)
      where: (relevance = true AND out()[relevance != true).size() = 0}
return someNode
```

You can change the WHILE and WHERE conditions to slightly change the behavior regarding which nodes you want to include/exclude based on relevance flag

Comment: This is awesome!  I think this helps me understand something else too, where I can chose where based on relation matching too.    Im not familiar with the out()[condition] syntax.  Can I append more traverse functions to that?  out().in()[condition]?

Comment: Hmm, i have to add an operator

Comment: I see, this should do all nodes that are one step that are relevant.  But what if i want 2 steps (or any depth) away?

Comment: I'm not sure of what you exactly need... do you want pairs (x, y) where x has id = 123 and y is at any distance from x AND all the nodes in between have relevance = true?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I'm talking about.

From your previous example I believe it only shows you 1 step away from id =123

Comment: I just added some comments above

Comment: Thank you!  Great product btw.